# Cannot set aria-expanded property on A tag

Tags: structr

I was attempting to create an accordion on a page using Bootstrap v.4.0 following [this example](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#accordion-example)

I need to set the aria-expanded and aria-controls properties of the A element.

In the UI for the page, I edit the properties of the A element, select the HTML Attributes tab, click on Show All Attributes and scroll down to the blank box at the bottom.

I am able to add a 'data-toggle' property, with the value 'collapse'

When I try to add a 'aria-expanded' property with the value 'false' a message flashes up in green saying that it has been added and saved with the value false, but when I close the edit properties box, the property disappears.

If I examine the resulting page in a browser, the aria-expanded property does not show up in the page source.

How should I add and set these properties ?

(Structr 2.1.3)

Answer (score 2):

The 2.1.3 release does not support setting arbitrary properties on HTML elements (only predefined ones and those prefixed with "data-"). This limitation has been removed in 2.1.4, so please try the current snapshot which should solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly. I tried a snapshot download (top one on the download page at https://structr.org/download) but got the exact same behaviour.
Is the top file listed the latest snapshot ? There isn't a file date or id, just a file size, so I can't tell which one is the newest !

Comment: The bottom one was the newest, there apperently were some problems with removing the previous versions.. :) There now is just one file for each type so please try again.